# Contents section is displayed in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the problem that the table of contents includes the Contents itself at page 0. Unfortunately I don't know how to change this to exclude the contents from being listed.
So far my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{article}
%import geometry class to ensure correct margins for document
\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm, top=2.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,citestyle=nature,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}


\addbibresource{literature}


\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,
    giveninits=true,
    natbib=true,
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%adds "Page" above page numbering
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}   

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I change this? Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: The author of `tocbibind` seems to like adding the table of contents entry in the TOC itself. It also happens with the `memoir` class (by the same author), where one has to type `\tableofcontents*` to avoid inserting the entry. I find it the same problem as “should the inventory be listed in the inventory?” Self-reference at the highest degree… ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use this command "\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}" in the preambles.

You may modify your code as follows..

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright]{article}
%import geometry class to ensure correct margins for document
\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm, top=2.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,citestyle=nature,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}


\addbibresource{literature}


\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,
    giveninits=true,
    natbib=true,
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%adds "Page" above page numbering
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}   

\include{introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This simple line solved the issue